# partitioning a usb stick with gparted

Tags: partition, gparted, usb-device

I need **partitioning** my **USB stick** into two parts.

Specifically my aim is to install Windows-to-go on the second partition and use the first one as a multiboot device for my Linux distros; these distros are already installed on it and so I prefer **not to delete the current partition**, if possible, so I would like to resize it only without affecting the files.

This is what I've been trying to do so far:

I inserted my USB stick, I could open and explore the files and even copypaste them on it, create folders and so on, so apparently it doesn't  have any problem.
I run *Gparted* on Kali *Linux* and selected the device, it could see it but an *exclamation mark* appeared on it and when I right-clicked and tried to *resize* the current partition *I couldn't* do it.
By clicking on the exclamation mark I got the following **errors** (see the message into the grey window in the middle, it says that the device is not mounted ):

[image: screen]

At the end of the message it also says that I probably miss two packages (*dosfstools* and *mtools*), then I run `apt-get install` to get them but it seems they are already installed.

---

Furthermore, on the terminal I run `parted -l` and `fdisk -l` and obtained the following outputs:

1) `parted -l` gives ->

```
    Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  968GB   968GB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      968GB   1000GB  32,2GB  extended
 5      968GB   999GB   30,9GB  logical   ext4
 6      999GB   1000GB  1356MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA INTEL SSDSC2CW06 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 60,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  105MB   104MB   primary  ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   60,0GB  59,9GB  primary  ntfs


Model: KINGSTON DataTraveler 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 15,6GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  15,6GB  15,6GB  fat32
```

2) `fdisk -l` gives ->

```
    Disk /dev/sdb: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders, total 117231408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x26443af5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      204799      101376    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          206848   117227519    58510336    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xfe2335fe

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1890607103   945302528    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2      1890609150  1953523711    31457281    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1890609152  1950873599    30132224   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1950875648  1953523711     1324032   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 15.6 GB, 15552479232 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 14832 cylinders, total 30375936 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x20ac7dda

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   ?  3224498923  3657370039   216435558+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2   ?  3272020941  5225480974   976730017   16  Hidden FAT16
/dev/sdc3   ?           0           0           0   6f  Unknown
/dev/sdc4        50200576   974536369   462167897    0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: I added a section on the question above with the output I obtained because I could not post a comment with too many characters.

Comment: ok. There was a mistake on the code, I edited it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above output (repeated below) the USB device does not contain a partition table.  Instead the device is formatted entirely with the fat32 file system starting at 0.  This means that no space was left at the start of the device for a partition table.

```
Model: KINGSTON DataTraveler 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 15,6GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  15,6GB  15,6GB  fat32
```

If you wish to work with devices without partition tables then use at least GParted v0.22.0.  Currently the most recent version of GParted is 0.25.0.

Comment: I performed `sudo apt-get install gparted` and the output says that I already have the newest version installed..

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that... I guess Fedora is pretty new, I can run it in live mode from the USB stick: in your opinion may I work with the partition of the same device when I'm running a live distro from there, since I just want to resize it and format the new empty one in ntfs?